# VB.NET form issue with ODBC when loading on windows7. Access to net framework folder denied

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-7, odbc

I'm new to vb.net..
We recently created a form which loads lists after connecting to our IBM iSeries Server. The Form is working as intended on Win8 and also checked with XPs and working too.
I'm compiling the file and getting the .exe to a certain folder and running the app from this folder (i.e. C:\My Programs\VB_Apps).
During compilation I used the any_cpu/x86/x64 options and also had the same problem.
The app is making a connection that uses the ODBC driver (also tried OleDB driver and had the same issues).
When the app is called from iSeries the window is getting load, but at the time of connection the App stops and getting the following message:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticOpenStreamForRead(String streamName)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.get_Switch()
   at System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
   at System.Data.Common.ADP.IsSysTxEqualSysEsTransaction()
   at System.Data.Common.ADP.NeedManualEnlistment()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
   at app1.Form1.SQLAS_header()
   at app1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam).`
```

This error occurs on both x64 & x86 machines. The only common characteristic of the machines that getting the error is that all using win7.

Does anyone faced anything similar before or knows what i might doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the line(s) of code that is crashing

Comment: Make sure excel can connect to your iseries then connect the VB program the same way as excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the user running application has access to path.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Assign Permissions to User.

Answer (score 0):

User has persmisions, another thing I realized is that by changing the or current driver from client access odbc  to iseries odbc the win7 x64 worked. All those computers with win7 x32 still not working. I think we need to replace all the win7 with win8 or newer,  but still this will be an issue that worries me since I don't have a given solution so as to trust my app to wok in production environment..

Thanks so far and in advance